# Understanding result returned from splice in CoffeeScript

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, splice, array-splice

I am using CoffeeScript along with the JS splice function.  My understanding of the JS splice function is that it should return the objects that were spliced out and modify the original array.  This seems to work ok with simple arrays but when I start adding objects to the array things break down.  Below is a simplified case with comments:

And a link [code](http://coffeescript.org/#try%3aclass%20Thing%0A%20%20do%3A%20-%3E%0A%20%20%20%20alert%20%22Hi%22%0A%0A%0Aa%20%3D%20new%20Thing%0Ab%20%3D%20new%20Thing%0A%0Aarr%20%3D%20%5B%5D%0A%0Aarr.push%28a%29%0Aarr.push%28b%29%0A%0Aarr%5B0%5D.do%28%29%0A%0Aresult%20%3D%20arr.splice%280%2C1%29%0Aalert%20result.do%28%29)

```
#Class that will go in array
class Thing
  do: ->
    alert "Hi"

a = new Thing
b = new Thing

arr = []

arr.push(a)
arr.push(b)

arr[0].do()  # this works

result = arr.splice(0,1)
alert result.do()  # this does not work
```

Does splice do something that makes this not work?  If anyone has an idea about the reason this is happening and/or a fix, I would be very appreciative,

Comment: `splice()` doc https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`Array.splice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) returns an **array** of the element(s) removed; as it has the potential to remove multiple via the second parameter:

Because of this, you should be using `alert result[0].do();`

[Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Cjtaa/](http://jsfiddle.net/Cjtaa/)

Comment: is mootols on jsfiddle equivalent to coffee script?

Comment: @andi: No. MooTools is a JavaScript framework, similar to BackBone, Angular, Knockout etc. In JsFiddle, expand the "Languages" section in the left-hand settings bar, and you can see you can change the "JavaScript" editor pane to "CoffeeScript" instead.

Answer (score 1):

`splice` returns an `array`.

So you need to do:

```
result = arr.splice(0,1)
alert result[0].do()
```